# JSONModel used with Objects/Dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, jsonmodel

Ive been working with JSONModel, the tutorials are making sense. They are parsing JSON contain an array with multiple indexes.

***I wanted to make sure JSONModel allowed to be used with say this dataset: https://gist.github.com/ryancoughlin/8043604***

`tide` is not an array correct? But there is `tide.tideSummary` - which contains array of tide data across multiple days.

***AllTide.h***

```
#import "JSONModelLib.h"
#import "Tide.h"

@interface AllTide : JSONModel

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSDictionary<Tide> *tide;

@end
```

***Tide.h***

```
#import "JSONModelLib.h"
#import "TideSummaryStats.h"

@protocol Tide @end

@interface Tide : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<TideSummaryStats> *tideSummaryStats;

@end
```

***TideSummaryStats.h***

```
#import "JSONModelLib.h"

@protocol TideSummaryStats @end

@interface TideSummaryStats : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *maxheight;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *minheight;

@end
```

***TideDetailViewController*** - Displays a single location (detail view) vs a list of multiple locations

```
@interface TideDetailViewController () {
    AllTide *_objTide;
}

@end

@implementation TideDetailViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSString *locationQueryURL = @"http://api.wunderground.com/api/xxxxx/tide/geolookup/q/43.5263,-70.4975.json";

    //fetch the feed
    _objTide = [[AllTide alloc] initFromURLWithString:locationQueryURL                                         completion:^(JSONModel *model, JSONModelError *err) {

                                             NSLog(@"Tides: %@", _objTide.tide);

                                         }];
}
```

Been going through several JSONModel tutorials and it makes sense, I think I am having trouble where my JSON format differs from the tutorials. Again, where my `tide` does not return an array.

Would this be a good case to utilize JSONModel keymapper?

Any ideas? Let me know if I can provide anything else. Been diving around for some guidance, but a bit stuck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hey Coughlin why you are using third party lib for json

Comment: I thought it would help streamline, and organize classes based on the JSON I wanted to display.

Comment: simply use make asyncronus call to url and use jsonserilization to handle response data,all this are avalible in native apple.

Comment: @kamaleshkumaryadav Some of the items are nested JSON. Example: ```tide.tideSummary``` -- ```tide.tideSummaryStats``` -- ```tide.tideInfo``` - Did you see the returned data by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need **AllTide.h**

try this:

**TideDetailViewController** - Displays a single location (detail view) vs a list of multiple locations

```
@interface TideDetailViewController () {
  NSArray *arrTide;
}

@end

@implementation TideDetailViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSString *locationQueryURL = @"http://api.wunderground.com/api/xxxxx/tide/geolookup/q/43.5263,-70.4975.json";

    //fetch the feed
    [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString: locationQueryURL
                              completion:^(NSDictionary *json, JSONModelError *err) {

    arrTide = [TideSummaryStats arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:json[@"tide"][@"tideSummaryStats"]                                                ];

     NSLog(@"Tides: %@", arrTide[0]);

  }];
}
```

Comment: Then if I wanted to access "maxheight" - how would I access that? ```objectForKey``` ? And then convert to a string and assign to my label text?

Comment: arrTide is an array of TideSummaryStats, so declare for example    `TideSummaryStats *t = arrTide[0];` and test a log for "maxheight"
     `NSLog(@"Tide Max Height: %@", [t maxheight]);`